# .htaccess file not working in new server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I was using Xampp server before, and this is my code in Xampp server website, and it is working perfectly fine

```
ErrorDocument 404 /website/error404.html 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z-]+)/?$ user.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

But, Now i brought a real domain and a server, and shifted my whole website. This is my new .htaccess code, which is not working

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/error404.html 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([0-9A-Za-z-]+)/?$ http://example.com/user.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

The error document is working perfectly fine. But not the rewriteEngine on thing, which i use to make friendly URL's

Changes:

I added `/` after `^` and before `([0-9A-Za-z-]+)`

Instead of using `user.php`, i am using `http://example.com/user.php`

I think, `mod_rewrite` engine is `ON`, on my hosting: http://prntscr.com/fksdwj

Comment: Confirm if your hosting provider has rewrite mode on

Comment: Will that do bro? http://prntscr.com/fksdwj @Akintunde

Comment: Assuming you are using Apache... please make sure mod_rewrite is configured and active in your default Apache config (should be located here: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to prefix the substitution with the domain, just using the path is sufficient.

The pattern in a rule never starts with a slash, see [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

> **Per-directory Rewrites**
>
> - The removed prefix always ends with a slash, meaning the matching occurs against a string which *never* has a leading slash. Therefore, a Pattern with ^/ never matches in per-directory context.

This means, you must keep the same pattern as in the XAMPP server. Removing the unnecessary [`NC`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc) flag, and leaving out the domain, will get you almost the same rule as before

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z-]+)/?$ /user.php?name=$1 [L]
```

The only difference is the leading slash in the substitution part `/user.php`.